# How to send and array of strings as Parameter in Swagger UI for testing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, swagger, webapi

I have the following method:

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetGlobalPageTemplatesbyTags(List<string> tags)
        {
            var telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
            var tagLookups = new HashSet<string>(tags);
            try
            {
                var globalPageTemplateStore = CosmosStoreHolder.Instance.CosmosStoreGlobalPageTemplate;

                var globalPageTemplates = await globalPageTemplateStore.Query()
                        .Where(template => template
                            .Tags
                            .Any(tag => tagLookups.Contains(tag.TagName))
```

And in swagger it appears like this:

[image: api]

However when I enable remote debugging, the tags parameter is always null,

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your controller signature to: (Add the FromUri attribute)

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetGlobalPageTemplatesbyTags([FromUri]List<string> tags)
```

And add each value in a new line like this

```
"short"
"long"
```

Comment: doesnt seem to work either https://www.screencast.com/t/F4Gpxb9TZv

Comment: You dont need to add quotes around the words. In Swagger, you can simply write each string you want in the array in new line